# How to Display Remote Image?

Tags: php

I need to have a working remote IMG display using PHP, let's say like this:

```
<img src='$src' />
```

And I need to fetch the remote URL based on $id, where

```
<?php
    $id = "brown_fox";
    $url = "http://exampl.com/$id";

    get_remote_img($url) {
    // some code to get image which SRC is dynamic:
    <img id="pic" src="sjf5d85v258d.jpg" />

    $src="sjf5d85v258d.jpg";

    return $src

}
?>
```

I hope I explained it understandably.

Comment: What's the problem ?!

Comment: if the remote image src is simply `sjf5d85v258d.jpg` you would have to get the current page cause the image is relative to the page you are on

Comment: Sorry. No question, code with parse error, no explanation what you want...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you can do something like this:

```
<?php
  ...
  get_remote_img($url) { ...
  $src = get_remote_img($url);
  // Concatenating the result to the elements src attribute:
  echo '<img src='.$src.' />'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
<?php
    $id = "brown_fox";
    $url = "http://exampl.com/" . $id;
    ...
    function get_remote_img($url) {
    // some code to get image which SRC is dynamic:
    $src="sjf5d85v258d.jpg";
    echo "<img id=\"pic\" src=" . "\"" . $src . "\"" . "/>";

    return $src;
    }
?>
```

Also, if you want to send and receive query parameters in the URI dynamically through a form, you can take a look at [GET Request](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) in PHP.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what's the $src value.

Assume that there's a lot of content on that external url and just 1 image:
`<img id="pic" src="xxxxxxxx.jpg" />`

and I need to get the xxxxxx value.

Comment: Then you can simply use JavaScript to get the value of `src` attribute like this:

`var srcVal = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");`

Is this what you're trying to achieve? Sorry, the question is very unclear.
Without the DOM methods in JS, assuming you want to do it in PHP, you'd need to write a parser to extract that value out of it.